# PHP Codeigniter Load page with sleep delay

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to fetch data from database and show the result in codeigniter view with delay.

My code looks like this :

```
   function loadPage($data) {
       for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
          $this->load->view('mypage', $data[$i]);
          sleep(5);
       }
   }
```

But this only load page once and show all data. What I need is load page with `$data[0]`, delay 5 secs, load page with `$data[1]`, and so on.

Please advice. Thank You.

Edit :

> I want to do this with php. Not javascript or jquery.

Comment: Put sleep before load view.opening braces missing in for loop

Comment: @Bugfixer I've tried, but did not work.

Comment: sleep(5) should make a considerable delay. However the page will be loaded once the for loop is finished running. Do you mean that sleep function is not called?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal sleep function is called. The problem is, if I have 3 results in $data[]. Then the page will delay for 15 seconds (3x5) and then load page "mypage" with $data[1],[2] and [3].

Comment: @RubahMalam yes, that's how it's supposed to work. php is executed at the server side and will return the processed html to the browser. Do you want them to be displayed in the page one by one? like display first, then wait 5 seconds, then the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP processes in the server and returns the processed html to the browser. That's how it works. But as you have explained in the comments, I think what you wanted to do is display the content to the browser while the for loop is running.

To do that you need to use output buffering (AFAIK, CI already calls ob_* methods in the core) so it might cause problems (or may not work as you would expect.) However, instead of loading the view multiple times, I suggest you to pass the data to the view and loop it there (and display the result one by one with a sleep.)

You can do it this way.

in your controller:

```
public function index(){
    $data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $this->load->view('mypage', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

In your view (mypage.php):

```
<?php
while (@ob_end_flush());      
ob_implicit_flush(true);

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    echo $data[$i];
    sleep(3);
}
?>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Send the `$data` array to the view file as we cannot return from the view file back to the controller to execute the next line of code all the time.

Thus the code needs to be placed in the view file itself.

let `$data` be the array.

```
<?php 
    foreach($data as $row) {
?>
//use `$row` where you want to use in the HTML section of the view file
<?php
    sleep(5);
     }
?>
```

NOTE : One basic question after reading your code
You are calling view file from the controller function that's absolutely right.
But once the call is made and you are in view file are you calling the controller function to execute the next part of for loop?

Codeigniter is an MVC (Model - View - Controller) framework. It's really not a good idea to call a function from the view.